# Oracle, Create table with inline constraint declarations using a different tablespace

Tags: oracle, constraint, tablespaces

I have two questions about inline constraints declarations for Oracle tables:

1. Is it a bad practice? If so, why?
2. How could one declare a different tablespace for the primary key and index like it's done when using the [outline declaration](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/clauses002.htm#CJAHIEIJ)? Something like

```
    create table THIS_TABLE (
        id number, 
        constraint THIS_TABLE_PK (id) tablespace INDEX_TABLESPACE
    ) tablespace DATA_TABLESPACE;
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Like this:

```
create table THIS_TABLE (
  id number NOT NULL, 
  constraint THIS_TABLE_PK PRIMARY KEY(id) 
             USING INDEX TABLESPACE INDEX_TABLESPACE
) tablespace DATA_TABLESPACE;
```

`USING INDEX TABLESPACE` is the syntax - you weren't far off.

As far as good/bad practice is concerned, that's opinion-based, so not really something that should be asked here. The alternative is to use the `ALTER TABLE ....` syntax after table creation.

Comment: Well, now I feel dumb. I should have tried the same syntax as for an outline declaration. Thanks for the feedback!